# Selection of start of word in cell only

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if there is any way for me to select only the start of the word for my formula (see below)

```
=IFERROR(IF($Q1="ALLN",IF(OR($S1="NATIONSTAR"),"X",""),""),"")
```

"NATIONSTAR" has different forms of it on my spreadsheet so I just need this to pick up the word "NATIONSTAR" and everything that can follow after for example there is a "NATIONSTAR/BLANK" and a "NATIONSTAR/ BALNK" with that gap

Comment: Thank you YowE3K for the help. I'm fairly new to VBA but I'm trying :)

Comment: this is not vba, it is a worksheet function or formula.  vba is a coding language, it is different and uses different functions.

Comment: This is not VBA.  And it's not SQL.  You really have the wrong tags on the question.  (I think I will change them.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `LEFT` function to only select the left-most x characters:

```
=IFERROR(IF($Q1="ALLN",IF(OR(LEFT($S1,10)="NATIONSTAR"),"X",""),""),"")
```

And your `OR` function, operating as it is on a single value, is redundant, so that can be simplified to:

```
=IFERROR(IF($Q1="ALLN",IF(LEFT($S1,10)="NATIONSTAR","X",""),""),"")
```

And then you could combine the two tests with an `AND`, giving:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND($Q1="ALLN",LEFT($S1,10)="NATIONSTAR"),"X",""),"")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SEARCH:

```
=IFERROR(IF($Q1 = "ALLN",IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("NATIONSTAR",$S1)),"X",""),""),"")
```